# Math Intensive, Calculation Based Website - Which Language Should I Use?

Tags: java, c++, python, math, matlab

I am very new to programming.  I am familiar with HTML, C++ and learning PHP to start a database.

I want to make a website which tracks a stock price.  I have written various algorithms in Matlab however, MATLAB only has a to-Java conversion.

I was wondering what language would be the best to do a lot of calculations.  I want my calculations to be done in real time and plotted.  Would Java be the best language for this?

I can do the calculations in C++ but I don't know how to put the plots on the website.  Likewise I believe I can do everything in Matlab but the conversion looks a little sketchy.

I would be very thankful if someone with experience with Java, or I also heard python, would comment on my post.

Answer (score 7):

My advice: write the website code in Python with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and do the calculations in [Numpy](https://numpy.org)/[Scipy](https://scipy.org/). Those two libraries provide a very Matlab-like API for heavy computations. Their performance is excellent. [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is the associated plotting library.

Comment: +1: Python is a great language for web code and numpy is an excellent library for crunching numbers. Though using Java + the Matlab API would be fine too

Comment: Thank you, I think you answered my question very well.

I appreciate your time answering!

-Mike

Comment: Depending on how big and complicated the website is, you could also consider a microframework like flask or web.py.

Answer (score 1):

It's *not so much the language* that matters, it's *making sure that you have a good mathematics library for it*. MATLAB is neat because it does all that matrix math super fast for you, but of course you need to link it with another language like you said.

Your goal should be to either find a good math library for the language you like, or find a language with a good math library you like.

*For What It's Worth*: I know Python has [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) (scientific computing package) and [Sage Math](https://www.sagemath.org/) (a libre Mathematica clone).

Comment: Sage code is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike Mathematica

Comment: I see it as trying to achieve a similar goal.

Comment: You are right ... but I'd not call it a "clone"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **PHP** or **Java Web**.

Answer (score 0):

I would do C++ and write them to a database, then using php you can grab them from the same database and show them online, otherwise then java can do all that but make sure all calculations aren't done on the fly since that will kill your server, especially with stocks that can turn into a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to plot data, then you may be able to pass off some of the calculation to the google chart api:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/